# Order by existence of multiple has_one associations in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi I want to order my Rails AR query by existence of multiple `has_one` associations but with an `OR`

The idea is to have something like below... but wanna use it in `order`.

```
IF `guest_listings`.`user_id` IS NOT NULL OR `minor_listings`.`user_id` IS NOT NULL
```

I've been seeing something like this, but maybe for `has_many` associations?

```
User.select('guest_listings.*, count(users.id) as counter').order('counter DESC')
```

^ also not sure how to add an OR `minor_listings*.` here

I'm new to Rails. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use that statement in your `order()` (without the `if`). But you will need to `joins()` those other two tables.

UPDATE

Be careful when using `select` and fields from other tables. The result might be unexpected.

Your statement could look something like this:

```
User.select('`users`.*,  `guest_listings`.`user_id` IS NOT NULL OR `minor_listings`.`user_id` IS NOT NULL as o').joins(:guest_listings, :minor_listings).order('o desc')
```

(`desc` if entries with `true` should be ordered first)

Comment: Not sure how to form it in `order` that's why I asked here... but I'll try. Thanks. Is there a neat way to do it? By naming it `as` something? @Fallenhero